# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, gd

I am getting this error in all the functions of Image GD library.
[image]

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("src/bg.jpg") or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
function copyImage1($im, $dp1_name, $x1, $y1){
    $dp1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dp1_name);
    list($w1, $h1) = getimagesize($dp1_name);
    imagecopy($im, $dp1, 35, 130, 0, 0, $w1, $h1);
}
function copyImage2($im, $dp2_name, $x2, $y2){
    $dp2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dp2_name);
    list($w2, $h2) = getimagesize($dp2_name);
    imagecopy($im, $dp2, 618, 125, 0, 0, $w2, $h2);
}

$box = imagettfbbox(30, 0, "src/font.ttf", $user_name);
imagettftext($im, 23, 0, 53, 348, imagecolorallocate($im, 73, 184, 227), "src/font.ttf", "hello");
imagettftext($im, 23, 0, 628, 348, imagecolorallocate($im, 73, 184, 227), "src/font.ttf", "byr");
copyImage1($im, "http://graph.facebook.com/100001504336690/picture?width=153&height=143", 10, 10);
copyImage2($im, "http://graph.facebook.com/100001504336690/picture?width=138&height=158", 10, 10);

$file_name = "dump/" . rand(1000, 9999) . "-id-" . rand(1000, 9999) . ".jpg"; 
imagejpeg($im, $file_name, 80);
imagedestroy($im);


?>
```

The files are available at their place,

Code was working fine but now it is not working. I don't know wyy it is not working now..

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message here?  If we have to chase down a network address it's really hard from a screenshot :p

Comment: Did you look at the **Related** questions. I'll bet anything one of them is the same problem as yours.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? And is that really the entire error message? The other questions have more details after `failed:`.

Comment: If it was working before, what has changed? Your code? Your environment? Facebook's security policy?

Comment: It looks like your internet connection is down or something.

Comment: @Steve my Internet is fine

Comment: @MikeW nothing, I guess something on the server changed, but hostgator support is not trying to understand , they are saying consult developer

Comment: @Barmar yes, the ss shows the entire error message

Answer (score 1):

The server that is running this code has DNS servers which it uses to resolve domain names, in this case, `graph.facebook.com`. It's either that those DNS servers are down or the server is misconfigured and can't reach whatever DNS servers it's supposed to use.

Comment: It is not even able to open file on the same server (src/bg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Restarting apache server also resolved my issue.  I recently moved to a dedicated server so there were some initial DNS issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, it just needed a apache restart.